# Is there a tangible benefit in keeping the number of PBKDF iterations secret and not storing them with the ciphertext?

Tags: key-derivation, pbkdf-2, password-based-encryption, scrypt, pbkdf

Suppose I have a local file and it is encrypted with a symmetric key derived from a strong passphrase, unique salt and $x$ number of PBKDF (e.g. Scrypt) iterations. I am interested in keeping this file a secret for a very long time.

Suppose the user specifies the number of iterations themselves e.g. a random number between the lowest safe number e.g. 1000 to the highest feasible number e.g. 100,000 when they first encrypt the file. The number of iterations would *not* be hard coded into the program or stored alongside the salt and encrypted data. It would be remembered only by the user and entered as a separate parameter along with the passphrase when it comes time to decrypt the file.

If an attacker were to gain a hold of the storage device to perform an offline attack on the file's encryption, my thoughts are that this makes their job much harder:

- They still need to try all the possible permutations of each
  passphrase
- Each brute force attempt takes ~200ms due to the slow
  PBKDF
- They also do not know the exact number of iterations to try
  either and have to try each passphrase permutation and repeat the
  process for every iteration count.

The use case is that for day-to-day use the user stores the number of iterations alongside the salt and encrypyted data for ease of use and fast access. But when they are travelling and need to cross country borders where there is a possibility of their phone/laptop/device being confiscated, then they can choose to not store the number of iterations as an additional precaution.

The difficulty for the user is remembering the number of iterations to use as well as the passphrase. However this is just a small additional number to remember e.g. similar to a 4-5 digit PIN number. For some examples it could easily be written down on a random piece of paper, or added as a phone number to an entry in your address book. In other words, very easy to hide in plain sight and not likely confiscated along with the digital devices.

Another advantage is if the encryption uses a cascade of PBKDFs to produce a final derived key e.g. 7328 iterations of PBKDF2-SHA2 then feed the result of that into Scrypt with 4755 iterations. Now the user remembers the two numbers (or stores them in the address book) but it has a multiplier effect on the cracking difficulty for the attacker.

- Do you concur that this is a reasonable feature to have in an encryption program?
- Can you quantify how much additional security is gained from keeping the number of iterations secret from an attacker as well e.g. $n$ bits?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is a good idea, for two main reasons.

Firstly, you are basing your security on the obscurity of a parameter that was not designed initially for being secret, which is a risky practice. It is similar to hiding the salt.

Secondly, following your example, you may in principle think that a random number of iterations between 10 and 100,000 is providing you with (roughly) 17 bits of additional entropy. That is, in addition to your initial secret password (with $K$ bits of entropy), you have to store the number of iterations, so your final secret is $K+17$ bits long. However, you are not actually gaining that additional level of security, since the iterative process for key derivation is, indeed, iterative, and for each password attempt, the partial results of each iteration can be reused for the next one.

The cost of a brute-force attack against a standard key derivation method will roughly be $2^p\cdot C \cdot N$, where $p$ is the bit length of the initial password, $C$ is the cost of each iteration (typically a hash-based function), and $N$ is the default number of iterations (e.g., 1000 iterations).

The cost of a brute-force attack against your approach will roughly be $2^p\cdot C \cdot 2^{17} = 2^{p+17}\cdot C$, since for each password you will perform $2^{17}$ iterations in the worst case. That is, your approach is, in the worst case for the attacker, equivalent to the standard one with the "highest feasible number of iterations" (as you put it in the question). To see this, consider the following example of brute-force attack to your approach: the attacker is trying different possible passwords (first "aaaaa", next "aaaab", etc.). In your approach, the attacker doesn't know the number of iterations. Let's assume she is trying the i-th password, for instance, "aabhjk". It is clear that the attacker cannot reuse the work for previous passwords. The attacker starts brute-forcing "aabhjk" with the minimum number of iterations (1000), with no luck. Next, she has to try "aabhjk" for 1001 iterations, but she doesn't start from scratch. She reuses the work done before with the 1000 iterations, and perform an additional one. This strategy is repeated until reaching "the highest feasible number of iterations", as you put it. That is why, at the end, your approach is similar (in terms of a brute-force attack) to simply using a very high number of iterations.

If instead of following your approach, you append those extra bits (i.e., the bits required for storing the number of iterations) to your password, and simply use the standard key derivation method, then the cost of a brute-force attack is $2^{p+17}\cdot C \cdot N$.

That is, your approach is, in fact, weaker than simply using the number of iterations as a suffix to the password. From a quantitative perspective, it could be approximately $N$ times weaker, where $N$ is the default number of iterations.

Comment: "you are basing your security on the obscurity of a parameter that was not designed initially for being secret, which is a risky practice. It is similar to hiding the salt." No. The security is fundamentally based in the strength of the PBKDF algorithm, the strong passphrase, the length of the salt and the *minimum* number of iterations. No security is lost  by hiding the number of iterations from the attacker. Also hiding the salt (e.g. in a separate keyfile) would hinder the attacker cracking the password significantly.

Comment: "However, you are not actually gaining that additional level of security, since the iterative process for key derivation is, indeed, iterative, and the partial results can be reused for the next iteration." If the attacker wants to store the previous results of their brute force attempt then that will require an infeasible amount of storage. Also instead of doing the calculation on the processor they have to find and read the previous result from storage which would likely slow down the attack. Also why not just append the number of iterations to the end of the salt to prevent them doing that?

Comment: "That is, your approach is, in fact, weaker than simply using the number of iterations as a suffix to the password." The point is not to increase the length of the password with another number they need to remember because the user could simply increase the password length themselves with random characters which would have more entropy. The point is that by hiding the number of iterations from an attacker it is a simple way to add more work for the attacker. It does not at all make it weaker than storing the number of iterations right next to the ciphertext which is the main comparison.

Comment: @itercryp "No security is lost by hiding the number of iterations from the attacker." That is only true if you are comparing your approach to the regular one. However, your approach requires the user to remember an additional secret, so, to be fair, you have to take that factor in consideration during the comparison,  My point is that it would be better to use that additional secret as part of the original password, rather than using for hiding the number of iterations.

Comment: @itercryp "If the attacker wants to store the previous results of their brute force attempt then that will require an infeasible amount of storage." I am not talking about reusing attempts for different passwords, but to reuse the partial results of the iterations for the *same password*. Basically, from the point of view of a brute-force attack, your approach is strictly weaker than simply using the "highest feasible number" of iterations.

Comment: @itercrypt Consider this brute-force attack to your approach: you are trying different possible passwords (first "aaaaa", next "aaaab", etc.). You don't know the number of iterations. Now you try "aabhjk", for instance. It is true that you cannot reuse the work for previous passwords. You start brute-forcing "aabhjk" with 1000 iterations, with no luck. Next, for "aabhjk" and 1001 iterations you _don't_ start again. You _reuse_ the work done with the 1000 iterations, and perform an additional one. That is what I'm talking about.

Comment: Yes I see that, they can try one password permutation at a time with all the possible iterations and re-use the previous results. However I think you missed my second comment - you can prevent that by appending the secret number of iterations to the end of the salt on initial encryption and at decryption time. This means attackers can't re-use the partial results. If the user chose randomly say 5000 iterations, then an attacker is now forced to try every possible iteration (up to 100,000) against every password permutation. What is the added security in this scenario?

Comment: OK, I see. Basically you are increasing the size of the salt. But then, what's the point of doing this? In your approach, the user has to remember the password and the number of iterations (e.g, "puppies" + 5000). Why don't just remember the password "puppies5000"? Recall also that users suck when it comes to remembering things.

Comment: Because adding a number from 1000-10000 to the password adds very little entropy. Keeping the salt hidden forces an attacker to do 99,000+ iterations for _every_ password permutation while the user still only ever has to do the number of iterations they specified. The point is that the option of forgetting/remembering the number of iterations can be done with a toggle switch in the user interface if you need to do a quick trip overseas. For day to day it's probably not something you would enable.

Comment: OK, but again, then the approach is similar to increasing the salt and hiding/encrypting a part of it. The number of iterations is not very relevant, IMHO. Yes, you are increasing the workload of a brute-force attack, but you could increase it at least to the same degree appending the number of iterations to the password.